# IMPRIMIR EN COLUMNAS EN C

Tags: c, estructuras-de-datos, printf

tengo un ejercicio de estructura de datos y en el enunciado me ponen un ejemplo de ejecución donde el output  sale así (las características de la piscina salen en tres columnas y dos filas):

Ancho de la piscina no es correcto: inicial = 21.0 calculado = 20.0

Se ha modificado el ancho de la piscina

Volumen de la piscina no es correcto: inicial = 2625.0  calculado = 2500.0

Se ha modificado el volumen de la piscina

********************* Características de la piscina *********************

Profundidad = 2.5         Largo = 50.0                 Ancho = 20.0

Ph = 6.5                  Volumen = 2500.0             Temperatura = 26.5

Carriles = 8              Ancho del carril = 250.0     Uso deportivo = N

---

Pero a mi me sale así:

********************Características de la piscina*************************

Profundidad = 2.50

Largo = 50.00

Ancho = 20.00

PH = 6.50

Volumen = 2500.00

Temperatura = 26.50

Carriles = 8

Ancho de los carriles = 250.00

Uso deportivo = N

Aún no he aprendido a imprimir en columnas ya que hacemos las prácticas antes de la teoría y al buscar en google no encuentro la forma de conseguir columnas sin incluir una librería. Alguien me podría indicar como hacerlo?

Este es el código del programa:

````
    ```
    #include<stdio.h>
    
    typedef struct
    {
        float pm, lm, am, ancho, PH, vm, acarriles, T, total;
        int ncarriles;
        char uso;
    }
    tpiscina;
    
    int main(){
        
        tpiscina p;
        p.pm=2.5;
        p.lm=50.0;
        p.am=21.0;
        p.PH=6.5;
        p.vm=2625.0;
        p.T=26.5;
        p.ncarriles=8;
        p.acarriles=250.0;
        p.uso='N';
        
        p.total=p.lm*p.pm*p.am;
       
        if(p.am!=p.acarriles || p.am!=p.ncarriles){
            printf("\nNo es coherente \n");
            p.ancho=p.ncarriles * (p.acarriles / 100);
            p.am=p.ancho;
        }
        
        if(p.vm!=p.total){
            printf("\nVolumen de la piscina no es correcto: inicial = %f calculado %f", p.vm, p.total);
            p.vm=p.total;
            printf("\nSe ha modificado el volumen de la piscina");
        }
    
         printf("*************Caracteristicas de la piscina*******************\n");
         printf("Profundidad = %.2f\n ", p.pm);
         printf("Largo = %.2f\n", p.lm);
         printf("Ancho = %.2f\n", p.ancho);
         printf("PH = %.2f\n", p.PH);
         printf("Volumen = %.2f\n ", p.lm * p.ancho * p.pm);
         printf("Temperatura = %.2f\n ", p.T);
         printf("Carriles = %d\n ", p.ncarriles);
         printf("Ancho de los carriles = %.2f\n ", p.acarriles);
         printf("Uso deportivo = %c\n ", p.uso);
    }
    ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar en printf la notación [%{integer}(d|f|c)](https://www.delftstack.com/es/howto/c/printf-align-columns-in-c/) para indicar los espacios, simplifico tu código para mostrarte un ejemplo de uso:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    
    printf("%-20s %-20s %-20s %-20s %-20s %-20s %-20s %-20s %-20s\n","Profundidad","Largo","Ancho","PH","Volumen","Tempetarura", "Carriles", "Ancho carriles", "Uso deportivo");
    printf("=======================================================================================================================================================================================\n");
    printf("%-20f %-20f %-20f %-20f %-20f %-20f %-20d %-20f %-20c\n",2.0,6.0,3.5,7.0,10000.00,22.0, 4, 1.8, 'N');
    printf("=======================================================================================================================================================================================\n");
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!